# Manually hiding bootstrap tooltips

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have Bootstrap tooltips on elements on my page that are misbehaving when viewed on a mobile device.

```
<span id="glyphicon1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign tooltip-anchor" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip1"></span>
<span id="glyphicon2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign tooltip-anchor" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip2"></span>
<script>
    $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
                'container': 'body',
            })
    }
</script>
```

If tooltip1 is displayed by touching glyphicon1 and then the device is rotated while it is being displayed, tooltip1 is no longer in the correct position relative to glyphicon1.

I have circumvented this problem by hiding the tooltips when the device rotates.

```
$(window).on("orientationchange", function (event) {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("hide");
});
```

This hides the tooltip1 OK, but now the tooltip1 cannot be shown again by touching glyphicon1. If I touch glyphicon2 to show tooltip2, or touch anywhere else on the page first, I can then continue to use glyphicon1 as usual. I am assuming that Bootstrap still thinks that tooltip1 is still being displayed, and has to be hidden first.

How can I ensure the glyphicon1 works correctly as soon as the device is rotated?

Comment: Which element you are hovering to display tool-tip again.Update question with the HTML .

Comment: @AnilPanwar I have added some HTML for clarity

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or insert your code in snippet?Will understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Take two different elements for making tool tip on icon. First an "i" tag for icon and wrap it with "span" tag with tool-tip attributes.

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        });
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="tooltip1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign tooltip-anchor"></i></span>
    <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="tooltip2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign tooltip-anchor"></i></span>
```